# Error with Faye on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, faye

I tried to follow the [RailsCasts Episode 260](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye).

When I open the application I got this error (http://pastie.org/2108233):

```
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 213.229.110.100 at 2011-06-22 14:15:14 -0700
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by MessagesController#index as HTML
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered collection (0.0ms)
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered messages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 11.1ms | ActiveRecord: 14.1ms)
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 heroku[router]: GET strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=152ms status=200 bytes=1261
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 heroku[router]: GET strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/stylesheets/application.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=1403
2011-06-22T21:15:14+00:00 heroku[router]: GET strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/javascripts/jquery.min.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=85925
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 heroku[router]: GET strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 heroku[router]: GET strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/javascripts/application.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=167
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js"):
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 213.229.110.100 | 1272 | http | 200
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /stylesheets/application.css?1308777162 HTTP/1.1 | 213.229.110.100 | 892 | http | 200
2011-06-22T21:15:15+00:00 heroku[router]: GET strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-06-22T21:15:16+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 213.229.110.100 | 255 | http | 200
```

After sending a message I got this error (http://pastie.org/2108254):

```
2011-06-22T21:17:52+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /javascripts/jquery_ujs.js HTTP/1.1 | 213.229.110.100 | 953 | http | 404
2011-06-22T21:18:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:18:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:18:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/messages" for 213.229.110.100 at 2011-06-22 14:18:33 -0700
2011-06-22T21:18:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
2011-06-22T21:18:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+LO/4TumqBUqtgWiWRwrrALl7xnCM6W2nDVYIcjO/1A=", "message"=>{"content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 88ms
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template messages/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_serve_static_assets/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_disable_x_sendfile/app/views"):
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 heroku[router]: POST strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/messages dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=94ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 heroku[router]: GET strong-mountain-892.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-06-22T21:18:34+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 213.229.110.100 | 199 | http | 304
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem:

Source code:

https://github.com/ntenisOT/Faye-Example-Application

Server source code:

https://github.com/ntenisOT/Faye-Heroku-Cedar-RedisToGo

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a 404 on `javascripts/jquery_ujs.js` and a missing view template defined in `MessagesController#Create`. Doesn't appear to be Faye related. Can you verify that they exist?

Comment: Yes they exist. Because the app is running really well on localhost!

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the command `rails g jquery:install`